# Regular expression matching Android package name

Tags: android, regex

How can I check if a String is a valid Android package name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A valid Android package name is described in the AndroidManifest documentation for the package attribute:

> The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package

---

The following regular expression will match a valid Android package name:

```
^([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z\d_]*\.)+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*$
```

Example usage:

```
String regex = "^([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z\\d_]*\\.)+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\\d_]*$";
List<PackageInfo> packages = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
  if (packageInfo.packageName.matches(regex)) {
    // valid package name, of course.
  }
}
```

For a detailed explanation of the regex, see: https://regex101.com/r/EAod0W/1

Comment: This captures more than A-Z. I don't think a package name can be `Åęø.ßlah`

Comment: @cricket_007 you are correct. However, when I was testing this earlier I found other Unicode letters that were valid. I will have to do some more testing. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm correct, the above regex would illegally accept a String like "test1". According to official Android rules, a valid package name must have at least two segments. I suggest this improvement: ^([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z\d_]*\.)+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*$

Comment: @EitanSchwartz Nice catch. Updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JaredRummler This regex doesn't support hyphens... domain names can contain hyphens.

Comment: @AniketSuryavanshi The hyphen is not acceptable in an Android package name.

Comment: By extension, for those curious, the regex to match a valid component name should look something like this `^((?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*\.)+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*)\/\1?\.(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*\.)*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d_]*$`

Answer (score 2):

going off of @skeeve 's comment, you can use \w in place of [a-z0-9_]

Full Regex:

> /^[a-z]\w*(\.[a-z]\w*)+$/i

Explanation:

> i

global pattern flag for case insensitive (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

> ^

asserts position at start of a line

> [a-z]

matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case insensitive)

> \w*

\w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

* quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible

> (.[a-z]\w*)+

parentheses define a group

> \.

matches the character . literally (case insensitive)

[a-z] see above

\w* see above

> +

quantifier matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

> $

asserts position at the end of a line

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

I used this regex and **test it** depended on official document on android app id

> - It must have at least two segments (one or more dots). Each segment
> - must start with a letter. All characters must be alphanumeric or an
> - underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

```
String regex = "^(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:\d*[a-zA-Z_]*)*)(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\d*[a-zA-Z_]*)*)+$" ;
```

Comment: This regex is vulernable to certain regex dos attacks apparently, which i figured out by complete accident when my app froze. Testing against this hangs for example: `com.aliucord.guhhhhhhhhhhfhuhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh4343hh$`

Answer (score 0):

From the android development document, the naming rules for the application ID are:

- It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).
- Each segment must start with a letter.
- All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Here is the regular expression for these rules:

> /^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(.[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)+$/i

Comment: The description is right, but the regex is not correct. I believe it should be:

  ^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)+$/i

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/7545bd83b798aebabef687a6be2fc763800d8d94/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/util/AndroidUtils.java#L727

Following code doesn't check for java keywords not allowed in pkg name
eg break.app <<not valid pkg name

Check above link for full code

```
// This method is a copy of android.content.pm.PackageParser#validateName with the
  // error messages tweaked
  //Returns null if valid package name
  @Nullable
  private static String validateName(String name) {
    final int N = name.length();
    boolean hasSep = false;
    boolean front = true;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      final char c = name.charAt(i);
      if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        front = false;
        continue;
      }
      if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '_') {
        if (!front) {
          continue;
        } else {
          if (c == '_') {
            return "The character '_' cannot be the first character in a package segment";
          } else {
            return "A digit cannot be the first character in a package segment";
          }
        }
      }
      if (c == '.') {
        hasSep = true;
        front = true;
        continue;
      }
      return "The character '" + c + "' is not allowed in Android application package names";
    }
    return hasSep ? null : "The package must have at least one '.' separator";
  }
```