# Android regex to validate android App id not fully correct

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery

I am trying to validate Android App ID name, I used this regex pattern - `/com\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/` to do it but this only validates pattern of text **com.example.com**, but from my research I found out some apps on Google play have their bundle id names as eg **eu.og.com** or **au.gh.cc.com** or even **com.example.jk.com**, please how do I got about validating all this with Regex in Javascript.

```
<script>
var android_prop = "com.example.com"; 
regexp =  /com\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/;
if (regexp.test(android_prop))
{
alert("Correct Android name");
} else {
alert("Void Android name");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772067/regular-expression-matching-android-package-name

Comment: @sldraogn PHP is not there and secondly its C# not javascript, thank you.

Comment: Oh, i know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after checking and doing some searches I came up with a solution to solve the regex issue in Javascript and PHP, for someone that might have the issue in future.

FOR JAVASCRIPT :

```
//var android_prop = $("#android_apps_text").val(); - uncomment this if you want the value from a textarea for validation and clean off next line
var android_prop = "com.example.com || eu.gh.ho.com"; //any android name
regexp =  /^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$/i;
if (regexp.test(android_prop))
{ 
alert("Valid android app id.");
} else {
alert("Invalid android app id.");
}
```

FOR PHP :

```
//DO NOT CREATES MATCHES VARIABLE, COPY AND PASTE THE PHP CODE BELOW
$android_prop = "com.example.com || eu.gh.cc.com"; //matches all android pattern
$re = '/^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$/i';
if (preg_match_all($re, $android_prop, $matches)){
echo "Valid android app ID";    
} else {
echo "Invalid android app ID";
}
```